# Is it better to use one or two CDN?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate, cdn

In my ASP.NET MVC application, I reference three scripts from my local /Scripts directory.

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

I would now use a CDN to load them.

Is it preferable to mix two CDN and use Google for jQuery and Microsoft for jQuery Validate? This way, both could be done in parallel?

Or is it useless and it's easier to depend on a single CDN?

Comment: I don't think it matters either way, your app will fail if one fails (which it almost definitely won't)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true that the scripts could be loaded in parallel, but on the other hand it causes another domain lookup, which could actually take longer than loading the two scripts from the same domain.

You are also adding another [single point of failure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_point_of_failure). Both CDNs have to work for your page to work properly. Even if the risk is low for a failure there, it's still a risk.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I wanted to be sure: there is no advantage to using two separate CDN.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want it loaded in parallel? Scripts are naturally blocking in nature, and with good reason, as a there is a good chance that scripts are dependent on other scripts as well. Loading one when its dependency hasn't is most probably fatal. Especially here, since `jquery.validate` **is** dependent on `jquery`.

Comment: Merci. You too have answered to what I wanted to know. But I can check only one accepted answer.